# OpenCV не сохраняет изображение, если путь содержит кириллицу

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

В директории `test` находятся две папки, названия которых написаны на латинице и кириллице. В каждой папке есть изображение `input.png`. Выглядит это так:

```
+ test
|-- + test test
|   \-- input.png
|
\-- + тест тест
    \-- input.png
```

Мой скрипт использует библиотеку `OpenCV`. Нужно чтобы он сохранил изображение в ту же папку, откуда он это изображение взял. Для сохранения я использовал `cv2.imwrite()`. Пример кода:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = 'test\\test test'

image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(f'{path}\\input.png', dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imwrite(f'{path}\\output.png', image)
```

Код выше эту задачу выполняет.

Но, если заменить путь к файлу `test\\test test` на путь содержащий кириллицу `test\\тест тест`, то скрипт успешно завершится **без сохранения** изображения. Код выглядит так:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = 'test\\тест тест'

image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(f'{path}\\input.png', dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imwrite(f'{path}\\output.png', image)
```

Как мне сохранить изображение находящееся в переменной `image`, путь сохранения которого содержит кириллицу?

Comment: Что-нибудь пробовали из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330084/opencv-imwrite-doesnt-work-because-of-special-character-in-file-path или https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185605/how-do-i-read-an-image-from-a-path-with-unicode-characters

Comment: @СергейКох Нет, но сейчас попробовал. Спасибо! Первая ссылка решила мою проблему `cv2.imencode('.png', image)[1].tofile(f'{path}\\output.png')`. Думаю стоит написать это как `ответ`, т.к. комментарий я не могу отметить в качестве ответа.